# RMSE is low but the prediction result is inaccurate?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, python, cross-validation

I trained models with different models such as `Feedforward neural network`, `Support vector machine`, `XGBoost`. The RMSE for my train and test dataset looks great but the problems show up once I plot the `actual values` versus `predicted values`. Like for instance, the plot below is for the `XGBoost` model:
[image]

imagine the `RMSE` that I received from the model is `0.01` which means somehow overfitting while the plot does not seem to be overfitted.

Comment: It looks like you’re capturing a lot of the high spikes (off a bit on magnitude) and missing the low spikes, but if you’re happy with the RMSE, then what do you see as a problem?

Comment: @Dave you are right about being happy with `RMSE` but I needed to show the accuracy with plotting the actual values versus predicted values. How to do that?

Comment: You could spin it to say that you’re doing well when it comes to identifying the upward spikes, but the visual assessment is that you’re missing a lot of what happens.